# Populating DataGridView from JSON Array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, winforms, datagridview

I have a JSON with an array of products, which I want to load into my C# program as a list, and eventually, display it in a DataGridView.

JSON:

```
{
   "products":[
      {
         "name":"game",
         "url":"website 1",
         "cash_price":"£20.00",
         "category":"Playstation 4 Game"
      },
      {
         "name":"tv",
         "url":"website 2",
         "cash_price":"£200.00",
         "category":"electronics"
      }
   ]
}
```

Product class

```
class Product
    {

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("url")]
        public string url { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("cash_price")]
        public string cash_price { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("category")]
        public string category { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("url")]
        public string url { get; set; }

        public static IList<Product> products = new List<Product>();
    }
```

I run this code:

```
string input = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);

var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(input);
dataGridView1.DataSource = Product.products;
```

But in the DataGridView, all I'm shown is a blank grid with the headers name, url, cash_price and category. No actual entries inside the grid.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Please don't post links to images, just write that you get an empty grid. Also, please tag this as a WinForms question.

Comment: @dnickless Ahh sorry, all updated now

Comment: It doesn't look like you're setting the property `Product.products` to anything before setting the DataSource. JsonConvert won't set that static property for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide the Product type when deserializing like `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>`.

```
class ProductList
{
     public List<Product> products  { get; set; }
}

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductList>(input);
dataGridView1.DataSource = result.products;
```

You can probably skip the `JsonPropertyAttribute`s when the property name matches the JSON names exactly - as is the case in your example.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. However I tried doing this (adding the class etc) but now the data grid view is completely blank. The headers aren't showing anymore, just a blank grey box. I know i'm probably making a silly mistake somewhere but ive been fiddling around with this for 2 hours and I don't know what to do aha

Comment: I forgot to make `List<Product> products  { get; set; }` public. Example code updated, and tested this time :)

Comment: Hmm I updated my code but I still can't get anything to show and I can't figure out why, is there any way I can like join.me you my screen or something?

Comment: Heh heh oepsie, I changed the DataSource to `result.products`. Now it will actually bind to your list of Products.

Comment: Ahaha that worked perfectly, honestly thank you so much!! Really appreciate it :)